# Reverting selectbox option back if

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, .post

So i've a situation where I have a selectbox that makes a jquery .post call to another script on a .change event.

I was wondering if there is anyway i can revert the selectedoption back to the original default should something occurs or that my .post event fail?

Hi ppl, I'm sorry.

Here's the javascript code. I've made some amendments to it. I'm trying to get the second line to work as this code is not working now due to some errors(due to don't know what on the second line). My selectbox is part of a list so i'm not able to make it a unique id to it and to remember the box the user selects, i need to use $(this).

```
    $('.order_stateselect').click(function(){
        var val=$(this).find(":selected").val();
        $(this).change(function(){
            if(confirm('Confirm Order Status Change?')){
                var conduct_status_chge=$.post('/seller/helpers/order_status_change.php',{order_item_id:$(this).parent('td').siblings('.order_item_id').text(),order_item_status:$(this).find(':selected').val()},function(data){
                    alert(data);
                })
                .error(function() { alert("error"); })
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: There probably is, but with no code how should we know? You can atleast post the code for the select list and the change event !

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell without code, but I'll try

```
$("#selectbox").data('origValue', $("#selectbox").val());

$("#selectbox").on('change', function () {
   $.post(...).done(function () {
      // other stuff
      $("#selectbox").data('origValue', $("#selectbox").val());
   }).fail(function () {
      $("#selectbox").val($("#selectbox").data('origValue'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
 var value=$("#selectbox").val();
    $.ajax({
    type:post,
    url:"something.com",
    success:function(){

    },error:function(){
    $("#selectbox").val(value);
    }

    })
```

Comment: This answer should work for you. You can use $(this) to retrieve your original element, and revert to the default from there I would think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').val('defaultvalhere');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to select first option not regarding default value:

```
$('#selectId option:eq(0)').attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a global variable to save the option selected previously.  Once save you can just use that on your `error` Its something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
this.previousVal = 0;
function changeHandler(selectBox)
    {    

$.ajax({
type:post,
url:"URL",
success:function(){
//ur code
this.previousVal=selectBox.selectedIndex;
},error:function(){
//use previousVal and set the value back to the previous value
}

})


    }                           
</script>

<select id="changeLang" name="changeLang" onchange="changeHandler(this)"></select>
```